# How can I control this latch with Positive Logic?

Tags: digital-logic, latch

Here is a simple 2 transistor latch circuit controlled with 2 switches to ground. How can I control this using 3-5 volt sources instead of switches?

[image]

Comment: Of course you can turn around the circuit, exchange Vcc, GND and replace the NPN transistors for PNP types. Then you have switches to Vcc. But it would only work if the inputs are only driven high and are open instead of driven low.

Answer (score 1):

To control the circuit with positive logic, replace each of the switches with a general purpose low power transistor like shown in the circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foUevi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your input is fed from more than 5V power supply, you may consider increasing R1. Eg. 2k7 for 12V-15V.

The circuit may very well work with higher resistors, but you didn't spec any currents/resistors in yours so I have to be on the safe side.